# No medium found error on update-grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

```
root@ano:~# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-148-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-148-generic
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sda: open failed: No medium found
done
```